# Where can I check what was updated on the last update?

Tags: debian, logs, apt, upgrade

Once in a while, when updating my system after reboot I got a black screen. The problem seems to bee ATI drivers, but it's weird because even TTYs do not work.

For fix it I reboot on recovery mode, uninstall ATI drivers and then install them again and everything it's fine.

However, I'm trying to figure out which update is causing this. Is there any log where I can see which packages were updated the last time I updated the system?

Comment: Please see this post over at SU: http://superuser.com/questions/427390/what-is-the-dpkg-equivalent-of-rpm-ql-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a log file located here, `/var/log/dpkg.log`:

```
$ head -10 /var/log/dpkg.log
2013-04-03 07:57:59 startup archives unpack
2013-04-03 07:58:01 upgrade libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu2 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status half-configured libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu2
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status unpacked libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu2
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status half-installed libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu2
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status half-installed libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu2
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status unpacked libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
2013-04-03 07:58:01 status unpacked libpoppler19 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
2013-04-03 07:58:02 upgrade libpoppler-glib8 0.18.4-1ubuntu2 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1
2013-04-03 07:58:02 status half-configured libpoppler-glib8 0.18.4-1ubuntu2
```

Comment: I see that the most relevant would be gnome-session, gdm3 and xserver-xorg-core. I guess xserver-xorg-core will be the one causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use aptitude, you have to look somewhere different:

`tail -20 /var/log/aptitude` or `cat /var/log/aptitude`

For older, zipped logs, use this command

`zcat /var/log/aptitude.1.gz` or `zcat /var/log/aptitude.1.gz | tail -20`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to @slm's answer that `dpkg.log` entries can be interpreted as explained here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html

In particular, the `upgrade` lines are interpreted as follows:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS *action pkg installed-version available-version*

So, in
`2013-04-03 07:58:02 upgrade libpoppler-glib8 0.18.4-1ubuntu2 0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1`,

action = `upgrade`
pkg     = `libpoppler-glib8`
installed-version = `0.18.4-1ubuntu2`
available-version = `0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1`

If the dpkg command executed correctly, version `0.18.4-1ubuntu3.1` of `libpoppler-glib8` was installed over `0.18.4-1ubuntu2`.